# Поиск статического адреса указателя

Tags: c++, c

**Добрый день, столкнулся с такой проблемой: в ручную ищу статический адрес на указатель,чтобы при перезапуске приложения не приходилось пересчитывать адреса параметров которые мне необходимы.
Но после перезапуска приложения мои указатели дают информацию по неиспользуемым приложением участком памяти.**

**Я наверно не правильно выразился, я использую редактор памяти Cheat Engine.
И мне нужно грубо говоря написать трейнер.**

Алгоритм нахождения указателя:

1. Нахожу необходимый параметр(Например здоровье,тип данных Float)
2. Устанавливаю на данный адрес BreakPoint  на доступ
3. Нашёл необходимые инструкции(получил предполагаемое адрес,регистр,смещение)
4. Найденный адрес помечаю как указатель, используя найденные данные выше.
5. Повторение процедур 2-4 с  перезаписью указателя на пункте 4.

Comment: А никто не обещал, что адреса будут одни и теже.

Comment: даже _относительные_ адреса могут менятся.

Comment: тем более, что сейчас в почти всех осях применяются так называемая "рандомизация адресного пространства"

Comment: трейнеры устроены сложнее чем вы думаете. Они же не требуют от вас изменения параметров, чтобы отследить нужный указатель. Вы можете посмотреть на выделение памяти и попробовать "пройтись" по указателям. Т.е. найти точку старта (спросить у ОС). Потом взять от неё отступ перейти в какой-то класс, повторять нужное число раз. Но для этого нужно понимать _как_ работает программа.

Comment: У меня есть комплект рабочих адресов и у меня нет особой необходимости использовать дизассемблер и писать скрипт, для меня достаточно в ручную найти указатели и сохранить в таблицу.